# How to edit specific version of file in fugitive

Tags: git, vim, gerrit, vim-fugitive

Some content has been moved from a `.c` file to a `.h` file in my repository and I want to compare them to ensure that the new header is correct.  This is for a Gerrit review and I am assuming there's no simple way to do this using the Gerrit toolchain.

I am trying to edit the `.h` file in one window and the old version of the `.c` file.  When I issue the `Gedit FETCH_HEAD:path/from/root/to/file.c` always gives the following error: `E492: Not an editor command: Gedit FETCH_HEAD:path/from/root/to/file.c`.  I've also tried the command using the hash.

What am I missing?

Comment: Fugitive commands are only available when the current buffer is controlled by git or when vim is invoked on startup in a git directory. Are you editing a git controlled file before invoking the `:Gedit` command?

Comment: Apparently not.  I keep forgetting I have to do that.  If you want to create an answer that essentially says "Make sure you are editing a file in the repo before issuing the `:Gedit` command" I would accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fugitive commands are only available when the current buffer is controlled by git or when `vim` first starts up is in a git directory.

Just open any file in the git repository before issuing your `:Gedit` command.

```
:e path/from/root/to/file.c
:Gedit FETCH_HEAD:%
```

Note: Using `%` to represent the current file. See `:h c_%`

Answer (score 0):

Use the "git show" command to get the files/versions you want to compare:

```
> git show version1:file1 > any_name_1
> git show version2:file2 > any_name_2
```

Then open the files in gedit editor or (better) use some diff tool like, for example, [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) to see the differences between the two files/versions.

```
> kdiff3 any_name_1 any_name_2
```